# Difference between free and global variables

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

Is there any difference between free variable and global variable? Or they are just  synonyms? In which situations I should use one or another?

Comment: Every global variable is also a free variable, but not the other way around.

Comment: Does this question really relate to programming languages? The term "free variable" is more common in logics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They don't play in the same category.

The notion of *free variable* is relative to a scope. If a variable is present in a term (i.e. a subprogram) and its scope is larger than this term, then the variable is said to be *free* in that term.

A *global variable* is one whose scope is the whole program, or the whole file, or the whole module, or whatever scope is called “global” in the programming language you're considering.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia, Free variables and bound variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables),

> The term *free variable* refers to variables used in a function that are not local variables nor parameters of that function. The term *non-local variable* is often a synonym in this context.

Now [Wikipedia, Non-local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_variable) states:

> In programming language theory, a *non-local variable* is a variable that is not defined in the local scope. While the term can refer to *global* variables, it is primarily used in the context of nested and anonymous functions where some variables can be neither in the local nor the global scope.

The last quote is from [Wikipedia, Global variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable):

> In computer programming, a *global* variable is a variable that is accessible in every scope (unless shadowed).